# Azure IAM: Trigger external security challenge in OAuth2 with curl

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to obtain the access_token for my user in Azure IAM via OAuth2. I've built a `curl` command this way:

```bash
curl \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d "scope=openid" \
    -d "response_type=id_token+access_token" \
    -d "grant_type=password" \
    -d "client_id=${MY_APP_ID}" \
    -d "username=${MY_USER}" \
    -d "password=${MY_PASS}' \
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/${MY_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

However I'm getting:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50158: External security challenge not satisfied. User will be redirected to another page or authentication provider to satisfy additional authentication challenges...
```

We use MFA, however the curl call is not triggering it. What's the proper way to get the `access_token` in the MFA-backed OAuth2 flow?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created a user and enabled **MFA**:

[image]

I tried to generate the tokens in Postman using ROPC flow and got the similar error like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:clientID
scope:openid
grant_type:password
username:username
password:password
```

[image]

> **Note** that : ROPC Grant Type doesn't support MFA enabled users and will be blocked instead. Refer this  [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#constraints-for-ropc).

To get the **`access_token`** in the MFA-backend OAuth2 flow, you can make use of **[Authorization Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)** like below:

Make use of below endpoint to generate **`auth-code`**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?

&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=RedirectURI
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid
&state=12345
```

I **signed-in with the MFA enabled user** to generate the code like below:

[image]

[image]

**I generated the tokens by making use of below parameters:**

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecert
scope:openid
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectURI
code:code
```

[image]

You can also make use of **Implicit grant flow** for MFA enabled users. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).